# Sorting time algorithm in JS (start-end time format)

Tags: javascript

I'm looking for a sorting algorithm for sort some times in the next time format:
"00:00". I have been looking for it but I haven't  found it.
The algorithm have to arrange the times according **to the start and end time**.

I fill the next array with the times:

```
var hours_array = []
day = getDayFormated(day);
hour_from = getHourFormated(hour_from);
hour_to = getHourFormated(hour_to);
hours_array.push({
 day: day,
 hour_from: hour_from,
 hour_to: hour_to
});
```

Example of the format:
[image]

Edit: first must be ordered by "hour_from". Then, the elements that have the same "hour_from" value, must be reordered by "hour_to"

Anyone has some algorithm for it? Thanks for reading!

Comment: What is the expected order for that input array?

Comment: from 00:00 to 24:00 you mean? @MattEllen

Comment: So you want that array to be sorted? According to wich property only hour_from? And this from 00:00 (at the first position) to 24:00 (last position)?

Comment: @adriano009 You've added a screenshot of the unsorted array. Could you also write the expected result of the same array?

Comment: Please can you write out the sorted array in full. It is easier for us than interpreting what you have said.

Comment: edited again. Is needed to make two sort  turns. @MattEllen

Comment: What have you tried so far? Also, you make your job harder by storing formatted results to the array. You should consider removing `getHourFormated()` on what you want to add to the array. Unless of course that helps you in some way.

Comment: I need the time to be formated with this function, because I'm getting the data from another site. Then, I need to order the hours_array list using the criteria explained. @GetSet

Comment: Great. Where's your code?

Comment: I understand that you think you're being clear. That's fine, but for us to understand what you want It would be very helpful to see the expected sorted array. for example, do you want he output to be `[{day:"Sun", hour_from:"22:25", hour_to: "13:45"}, {day:"Wed", hour_from:"22:25", hour_to: "13:45"}, {day:"Sat", hour_from:"02:00", hour_to: "05:33"}, {day:"Thu", hour_from:"02:00", hour_to: "05:33"}, {day:"Mon", hour_from:"00:00", hour_to: "00:00"}]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will order by `day`, then by `hour_from` and then by `hour_to`:

```js
var weekDays = ["Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat"];
var list = [
    { "day": "Wed", "hour_from": "12:00", "hour_to": "14:00" },
    { "day": "Sat", "hour_from": "02:00", "hour_to": "05:33" },
    { "day": "Mon", "hour_from": "00:00", "hour_to": "00:00" },
    { "day": "Sun", "hour_from": "22:25", "hour_to": "13:45" },
    { "day": "Thu", "hour_from": "02:00", "hour_to": "05:33" },
    { "day": "Thu", "hour_from": "03:00", "hour_to": "05:33" },
    { "day": "Thu", "hour_from": "03:00", "hour_to": "06:33" }
];

list.sort(function(a, b) {
  var weekDiff = weekDays.indexOf(a.day) - weekDays.indexOf(b.day);
  if (!weekDiff) {
    var fromDiff = a.hour_from.replace(/[^\d]/g, "") - b.hour_from.replace(/[^\d]/g, "");
    if (!fromDiff) return a.hour_to.replace(/[^\d]/g, "") - b.hour_to.replace(/[^\d]/g, "");
    return fromDiff;
  }
  return weekDiff;
});

console.log(list);
```

If you don't want to use  the `day` you can just use

```js
var list = [
    { "day": "Wed", "hour_from": "12:00", "hour_to": "14:00" },
    { "day": "Sat", "hour_from": "02:00", "hour_to": "05:33" },
    { "day": "Mon", "hour_from": "00:00", "hour_to": "00:00" },
    { "day": "Sun", "hour_from": "22:25", "hour_to": "13:45" },
    { "day": "Thu", "hour_from": "02:00", "hour_to": "05:33" },
    { "day": "Thu", "hour_from": "03:00", "hour_to": "05:33" },
    { "day": "Thu", "hour_from": "03:00", "hour_to": "06:33" }
];

list.sort(function(a, b) {
  var fromDiff = a.hour_from.replace(/[^\d]/g, "") - b.hour_from.replace(/[^\d]/g, "");
  if (!fromDiff) return a.hour_to.replace(/[^\d]/g, "") - b.hour_to.replace(/[^\d]/g, "");
  return fromDiff;
});

console.log(list);
```

How it works:

[Array#sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) accepts a function with two parameters and returns a numeric value (smaller than 0 if the first item should appear first, 0 if they are equal and bigger than 1 if the second should appear first).

example:

```js
var list = [5, 2, 3, 4, 1];

console.log(list.sort(function(a, b) {
  return a - b
}));
console.log(list.sort(function(a, b) {
  return b - a
}));
```

The `replace(/[^\d]/g, "")` part removes all non numeric characters from the time string so that it can be used in a numeric operation.

example:

```js
var a = "12:34";
var b = "45:23";

console.log(a - b);

a = a.replace(/[^\d]/g, "");
b = b.replace(/[^\d]/g, "");

console.log(a, b);
console.log(a - b);
```

`a.hour_from.replace(/[^\d]/g, "") - b.hour_from.replace(/[^\d]/g, "")` returns a number smaller than 0 if a starts before b, 0 if they start on the same time and bigger than 0 if a start after b. So we can return the result unless if they are equal.

example:

```js
var list = ["12:34", "12:32", "13:21", "11:02"]

console.log(list.sort(function(a, b) {
  return a.replace(/[^\d]/g, "") - b.replace(/[^\d]/g, "");
}));
```

The same process needs to be run for `hour_to`.

Answer (score 0):

Solved:

```
var hours_array = []
day = getDayFormated(day);
hour_from = getHourFormated(hour_from);
hour_to = getHourFormated(hour_to);
hours_array.push({
 day: day,
 hour_from: hour_from,
 hour_to: hour_to
});
hours_array.sort(function (a, b) {
 return a.hour_from.localeCompare(b.hour_from);
});
hours_array.sort(function (a, b) {
 if (a.hour_from == b.hour_from){
  return a.hour_to.localeCompare(b.hour_to);
 }
});
```

Thanks for everyone!

Comment: [Array sort is not stable in some browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#Browser_compatibility), so the order might be a bit different than expected in different browsers if using more than one sort on the same array.

Comment: The function in the second sort returns `undefined` when the if condition is not true, which might result in unexpected order in some browsers

Answer (score 0):

Multiple sort conditions can be combined with `||` :

```js
var hours_array = [ { "day": "Wed", "hour_from": "12:00", "hour_to": "14:00" },
                    { "day": "Sat", "hour_from": "02:00", "hour_to": "05:33" },
                    { "day": "Mon", "hour_from": "00:00", "hour_to": "00:00" },
                    { "day": "Sun", "hour_from": "22:25", "hour_to": "13:45" },
                    { "day": "Thu", "hour_from": "02:00", "hour_to": "05:33" },
                    { "day": "Thu", "hour_from": "03:00", "hour_to": "05:33" },
                    { "day": "Thu", "hour_from": "03:00", "hour_to": "06:33" } ];

hours_array.sort(function(a, b) {
  return a.hour_from.localeCompare(b.hour_from) || a.hour_to.localeCompare(b.hour_to);
});

console.log( JSON.stringify(hours_array).replace(/},/g, '},\n ') );
```

Explanation: the result from [`a || b`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_OR) is `a` if `a` is not [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy), otherwise the result is `b`.

---

Or a bit simpler by concatenating the values :

```js
var hours_array = [ { "day": "Wed", "hour_from": "12:00", "hour_to": "14:00" },
                    { "day": "Sat", "hour_from": "02:00", "hour_to": "05:33" },
                    { "day": "Mon", "hour_from": "00:00", "hour_to": "00:00" },
                    { "day": "Sun", "hour_from": "22:25", "hour_to": "13:45" },
                    { "day": "Thu", "hour_from": "02:00", "hour_to": "05:33" },
                    { "day": "Thu", "hour_from": "03:00", "hour_to": "05:33" },
                    { "day": "Thu", "hour_from": "03:00", "hour_to": "06:33" } ];

hours_array.sort(function(a, b) {
  return (a.hour_from + a.hour_to).localeCompare(b.hour_from + b.hour_to);
});

console.log( JSON.stringify(hours_array).replace(/},/g, '},\n ') );
```